# messagereactionadd dont get triggered

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a problem with the `messageReactionAdd` event, it only works after a message is sent inside the discord.
I also tried to put a `console.log` at the beginning of the event but not even that is triggered.

This is my code:

```js
    module.exports = async (client, reaction, user) => {
    if(reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
    if(reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
    if(user.bot) return;

    if(reaction.message.channel.id === '837981337658589204') {
        reaction.users.remove(user);
        if(reaction.emoji.name === '') {
            //code...
        }
    }
```

partials:

```js
const client = new discord.Client({ partials: ['MESSAGE', 'REACTION']});
```

i have tried all the methods found on this site but it still doesn't work.

Edit: The solution to all of this was to activate Privileged Gateway Intents on the bot page, [like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJQuK.png). Thanks to [@Toasty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13685706/toasty)

Comment: Have you misspelled `Discord.Client({ ... })` or have you named it with a lowercase 'd'?

Comment: I called it with a lowercase 'd'

Comment: And other events are getting triggered?

Comment: yes, everything works except this

Comment: Is your event file spelled correctly?

Comment: the event works, but as I wrote, only after a message is sent inside the discord

Comment: Ahh so it's only getting triggered if you send a message?

Comment: it is not triggered after the bot restarts, it is triggered ONLY after something happens in the discord. If nothing happens within the discord it will never be triggered. idk why, i never had this problem before.

Comment: Its not getting triggered after restarting your bot because, as the name says, after somebody **reacts** to a `message`

Comment: yes i know, i mean that if i click the reaction after the bot is restarted nothing happens

Comment: Were you able to fix your error?

Comment: no, I was about to add an edit saying that the same file in another bot works, but in mine it doesn't. sorry for the late answer I just got up (11:05 CET)

Comment: I might have the solution: Try enabling [`Privileged Intents`](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents) in the [`Discord Developer Portal`](https://discord.com/developers/applications) under "Privileged Gateway Intents" in the "Bot" section

Comment: If you dont know what I mean, look at [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJQuK.png). Just enable these

Comment: i can't really believe this was the solution. How is it possible? in the second bot they are not enabled

Comment: Yeah, this feature is a bit weird but im happy for you that it works now, I'll update this to my question :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think** you don't need to check if the `message` is `partial`, but if the `reaction`is `partial`. Try this:

```js
try {
   if(reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
   if(user.partial) await user.fetch();
} catch(err) {
   console.log('Error: ' + err);
}
```

In the [`official guide`](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/partials.html#enabling-partials) it is checked if the `message` is `partial`, but this example is **not** about the `messageReactionAdd` event

---

### Edit / Update:

After looking through the guide again, I remembered one thing:

Try enabling [`Privileged Intents`](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents) in the [`Discord Developer Portal`](https://discord.com/developers/applications) under "Privileged Gateway Intents" in the "Bot" section.

If you don't know what I mean, look at [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJQuK.png). Just enable these and it may work now.

Comment: in my opinion the problem is not inside the event. Because is it not triggered at all, I think it has to do with the bot cache, could it be a problem if it is hosted on a vps?

edit: i tried as you told me and it doesn't work

Comment: @Klyde Mine is hosted on a `VPS` too and I never had any problems

Comment: i can't figure out what the problem is, it's literally the same code as my other bots working perfectly

Comment: So I doesn't trigger your event at all?

Comment: exactly, the event isn't triggered at all, it is triggered only after an action is performed inside the server (e.g. send a message)

Comment: Does your 'event trigger' look like this? `client.on('messageReactionAdd', function(messageReaction, user) { ... }`

Comment: Or this: `client.on('messageReactionAdd', (messageReaction, user) => { ... }`

Comment: no, like that, `module.exports = async (client, reaction, user) => {`

Comment: Can you update this line into your question?